# Get names from Dictionary's value as Comma separated value string

Tags: c#, linq, csv, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I Have a Dictionary `Dictionary<int, Foo> fooDic` as it's value is a class and `Foo` has a property `_barName` i Need all the names from `fooDic` as a CSV string... 
for example..

```
var fooDic = new Dictionary<int, Foo>()
{
    { 0, new Foo { _barId = 10, _barName = "some value" } },
    { 1, new Foo { _barId = 15, _barName = "some Foo value" } }, 
    { 2, new Foo { _barId = 25, _barName = "some Foobar value" } }
};
```

I need output as

```
string result = "some value, some Foo value, some Foobar value";
```

Please Share your ideas/solutions, How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
String names = String.Join(", ", fooDic.Select(x => x.Value._barName));
```

Take a look:

http://ideone.com/F4bLU

Comment: Use `", "` to add the white space.

Comment: +1, Cool. I added .ToArray by myself in my code as you forgot to add it earlier...however thanks for quick solutions Guys... :)

Comment: @MayankPathak: You don't need the `ToArray` with .NET 4(Ideone is mono), because `String.join` takes also an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421) now. The `ToArray` would create a copy first which is completely redundant and inefficient.